# Архитектура и взаимодействие контролов между собой

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

Хотелось бы литературы, описывающей архитектуру и взаимодействие контролов между собой на немного более глубоком уровне, чем «Тут мы наследуемся от `UserControl`, тут переопределяем пару методов, и это собственно всё, что вам нужно знать».

Для ясности слов «архитектура» и «взаимодействие», вот примерный список гложущих меня вопросов:

1. У каждого контрола есть свой `Graphics`. А как и в каком порядке они складываются в единую картинку?
2. Когда контрол хочет себя перерисовать, кого и как он об этом оповещает?
3. Где-то слышал про единый для всего приложения пулл событий. Как они расползаются до конечных контролов?
4. Как правильно убивать контролы? Простым `Dispose()` или ещё удалять из `parent.Controls`?
5. И т. п.

Буду рад подробной статье, но и от глав из книги не откажусь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы говорите действительно о `Windows Forms`, а не, например, о `WPF`, то вся эта библиотека является лишь хорошо спроектированной оберткой над частью `WinAPI` для работы с визуальными компонентами.

Поскольку тема достаточно обширная, то в кратком ответе все это рассказать не удастся; предлагаю вам начать изучение со статей по [**базовым принципам**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff657751.aspx) разработки оконных приложений и с изучения функции [**SendMessage**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) на `MSDN`.

---

*Далее - конкретно по вашим вопросам:*

1. `Graphics` сам по себе никуда не складывается, это лишь обертка над некоторым регионом формы, отрисовываемой с помощью `WinAPI`. То есть `Graphics` предоставляет возможность изменять механизм отрисовки конкретного контрола, *не затрагивая при этом общей логики этой самой отрисовки.* По поводу порядка - у каждого контрола есть свой `z-index`, который можно изменить, например, с помощью функции `Controls.SetChildIndex` и именно этот индекс учитывается при инвалидации формы.
2. Все сообщения в `WinAPI` проходят через так называемый [**Message pump,**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/b44f06fb-fc4a-4fac-87cd-48b2953ea5fa) при этом кто угодно может послать сообщение о перерисовке. Здесь для понимания следует прочесть статьи про сообщение [**WM_PAINT**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145213.aspx) и методы инвалидации - [**Controls.Invalidate,**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate.aspx) который на деле маршаллит методы типа [**InvalidateRect.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002.aspx)
3. См. (2)
4. Опять же из соображений использования `unmanaged` кода внутри `managed` (при маршаллинге вызовов `WinAPI`), необходимо освобождать все выделенные ресурсы типа `HXXRESOURCE`, это реализуется в методе `Dispose`. Поскольку форма является контейнером для других контролов, то именно она несет ответственность за их освобождение, т.е метод `Form.Dispose` по контракту должен вызывать методы `Dispose` для всех ее контролов. **Если этого не происходит, то это плохо.**
5. Если интересно, то можете изучить [**исходный код**](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid4DF064FFA4499D3C81DC177A9AC37FB9F079CF5B.aspx) `Windows.Forms` и посмотреть, как именно в нем все реализовано. Интерес представляет также альтернативная реализация `mono-winforms`. *Рекомендую также ознакомиться с идеологией `WPF` и задуматься над архитектурными решениями, которые были приняты в ходе разработки этой библиотеки.*

Comment: Спасибо за «базовые принцыпы», почитаю.

Далее по ответам:

 1. То есть я правильно понимаю, что есть один большой `Bitmap` (или его аналог) на всю форму, а контролам через `Graphics` выдаётся доступ к его областям?
 2. Получается, неперегруженный `Control.Refresh` сначала вызывает на себя `Redraw`, затем вызывает `Refresh` у всех дочерних контролов, и последний из них кидает WM_PAINT в Message pump? Если да, то непонятно разве что, как определяется последний.

Comment: @Jofsey
2. Не совсем. Идея в том, что на каждый контрол в очередь сообщений придет по одному сообщению `WM_PAINT`, при этом последовательность их прихода должна соответствовать видимому порядку. В простейшем случае реализации `Message Pump` все контролы обязательно бы перерисовывались по одному разу, "накладываясь" друг на друга. *Но в реальности обработка сообщений типа `WM_PAINT` отличается от обработки других сообщений, поскольку `WM_PAINT` валятся в `Pump` в огромных количествах.*

Comment: @Jofsey

В общем, `Message Pump` умеет группировать сообщения `WM_PAINT`, чтобы не осуществлять лишних действий и умеет группировать их по регионам (тут уже нужно смотреть исходные коды для деталей), то есть в финальном варианте весь этот набор сообщений `WM_PAINT` должен оставить только контролы, которые не перекрываются друг другом и перерисовать только те области, которые действительно нужно перерисовывать.

Comment: @Jofsey **Касательно (1).** В общих чертах, так и есть. Насчет памяти я сомневаюсь (чтобы тут что-то точно сказать нужно все-таки досконально изучить `MSDN` и исходные коды), но предполагаю, что операции над `Graphics` производят некоторый аналог `Lock / Unlock` для соответствующих областей, что, естественно, невозможно без накладных расходов.

Comment: Касательно (1). Если между `Lock` и `Unlock` просто приостанавливается вывод (отсылка `WM_PAINT`) (как между `SuspendLayout` и `ResumeLayout`), то не вижу никаких потребностей в дополнительных буферах.

Comment: Касательно (2) 0_O. Ведь это противоречит (1). Если для всей формы мы имеем один большой bitmap, то всё, что можно сделать, получив WM_PAINT — вывести его поверх окна (в лучшем случае, ограничиться только измененными областями). Но понятия «перекрывается» в такой системе существовать не может. Или я что-то не понимаю.

Comment: А ещё я не представляю, как в системе с кучей WM_PAINT'ов вообще можно их фильтровать. В чём проблема: когда в очередь поступает очередной WM_PAINT, можно либо обработать его, либо надеяться на то, что следом прийдёт ещё один, но вот подкрепить такую надежду нам как раз таки нечем.

Comment: @Jofsey Смотрите, чтобы стало понятнее, воспроизведу классический сценарий использования `Graphics` и посмотрим, как это дело маппится на native код (пока без оптимизаций и группировки `WM_PAINT` - об этом позднее):

1. Пусть в какой-то момент времени мы решили заинвалидейтить некоторую форму с набором контролов на ней. Это выполняется путем последовательной рассылки сообщений `WM_PAINT` (начиная с самой формы) в порядке, соответствующем Z-index.

Comment: 2. Каждый контрол получает сообщение `WM_PAINT` и в своем обработчике сообщений прокидывает это в managed (`C#` код) обработчику `OnPaint`.

3. Там из `PaintEventArgs` мы можем получить доступ к объекту `Graphics`, при этом начало действий с объектом `Graphics` вызывает `Lock` соответствующего региона формы, а окончание - `Unlock`. **Работа с битмапом как таковым присутствует только здесь и не выходит за пределы `OnPaint`.** Накладные расходы, про которые я говорил, идут на выделение `unmanaged` хэндлеров и на синхронизацию.

Comment: - После завершения `managed` части, то есть после выхода из кода `OnPaint` для данного контрола, управление снова возвращается `unmanaged` части, которая высвобождает за собой все, что нужно и на этом обработка `WM_PAINT` заканчивается. *Разумеется, что никаких прокидываний битмапов здесь не происходит.*

----------

**В общем-то, все, что я написал, не противоречит ответам на вопросы (1) и (2).**

Comment: @Jofsey Дальше - по поводу группировки `WM_PAINT`. Идея здесь в том, что сама по себе абстракция `Message Pump` сложнее, чем просто *"получили сообщение - обработали его."* Она асинхронна и отдельным образом умеет совершать некоторые действия **при добавлении** `WM_PAINT` в очередь сообщений. Поскольку перерисовка выполняется медленнее, нежели накопление сообщений, то часто получается так, что, в тот момент, когда `WM_PAINT` "падает" в очередь, там уже есть сообщение, идентичное данному, которое еще не было обработано. Понятно, что в таком случае новое сообщение можно discard'нуть.

Comment: Аналогично и для оптимизации с регионами - если при поступлении сообщения `WM_PAINT` в очередь в числе ближайших `N` сообщений есть запросы на перерисовку чего-то, что целиком лежит под объектом из нового `WM_PAINT`, то все такие старые сообщения discard'ятся. *Как здесь может применяться оптимизация по регионам, я думаю, вы догадаетесь)*